# Yii2 REGEXP in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

How can I use an SQL query like the following in yii2?

```
select * from Skill_Names where SkillName REGEXP 'PHP|MYSQL'
```

I don't want something like `( SkillName Like %PHP% or SkillName Like %MYSQL% )` as I need to use REGEXP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simplest would be direct query:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand("select * from Skill_Names where SkillName REGEXP 'PHP|MYSQL'")->queryAll();
```

<strike>If you have an `ActiveRecord` class for the `Skill_Names` table you could also use an `Expression`:</strike>

`SkillNames::find()->where(['SkillName' => new \yii\db\Expression("REGEXP 'PHP|MYSQL'"])->all();`

edit: Regarding your comment: You can simply use the where part literally as a string, it will be returned as is:

```
SkillNames::find()->where("SkillName REGEXP 'PHP|MYSQL'")->all();
```

edit 2: Your own solution in operator format:

```
SkillNames::find()->where(['REGEXP', 'SkillName','PHP|MYSQL'])->all();
```

Comment: it generating `SELECT * FROM Skill_Names WHERE SkillName=REGEXP 'PHP|MYSQL'` see `=` before `REGEXP`.

Comment: correct format `SkillNames::find()->where(["REGEXP","SkillName",'PHP|MYSQL'])->all();` thanks @Blizz

Comment: That's operator format, another nice alternative. Had no idea that `REGEXP` was supported as operator, cool. I'll add it to the reply.

Comment: What if 'PHP|MYSQL' comes from the user, is there a way to escape it in the operator format ?